What are the benefits of kaal bhairava ashtakam?
What are the results obtained according to the scriptures when an upasakas chants the kaal bhairava ashtakam ?
Can this mantra be chanted infront of a banalinga ?

Benefits of chanting Kalabhairava ashtakam is mentioned in 9th and last verse of the stotra:

कालभैरवाष्टकं पठंति ये मनोहरं ज्ञानमुक्तिसाधनं विचित्रपुण्यवर्धनम्
। शोकमोहदैन्यलोभकोपतापनाशनं प्रयान्ति कालभैरवांघ्रिसन्निधिं नरा
ध्रुवम् ॥९॥
Those who Read the Eight Verses on Sri Kalabhairava with Devotion
which is Heart-Stealing and Charming, Will be Lead straight to the
Goal of Knowledge and Liberation and Will result in the Rise of
Various Auspicious Qualities and Which Destroys (mental) Sorrows and
Afflictions, Delusions and Infatuations, Wretchedness and Depressions,
Passions and Anger and (mental) Heat and Burns and after Death the
Devotee will Surely Attain the Feet of Sri Kalabhairava.


What about the sins that we acquire throughout our millions of lives ? @cracklingcyclone

@Sillyasker nothing about that is mentioned

Also does it grant fearlessness ? @cracklingcyclone?

@CracklingCyclone would you please take a look into this question?
